# Wordpress show content if current user get spesific role and spesific meta value

Tags: user-roles, conditional-tags, meta-value

How to make conditional if statement like "Show content if current user get spesific role and spesific meta value", if not.. hide content

```
<?php if( ( current user get spesific role and spesific meta value) ) { ?>
show content
<?php } else { ?>
hide content
<?php } ?>
```

i have no idea... please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs some additional context, but here's a generic approach to what you've described.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
 
    // Does user have the required role?
    if ( in_array( 'some_role', $user->roles ) && 'some_meta_value' == get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'some_meta', true ) ) {

        // Special content...

    } else {

        // User doesn't have access...

    }
} else {
    // Optional "else" condition if user is not logged in...
}
```

Note: this is based on checking if the user has a specific role as you described.  However, WP is a "permissions based" user system.  You really would be better off checking capabilities so that if you have two (or more) roles with overlapping capabilities, you can just check for that instead of having to account for specific roles.  For example:

```
 `if ( current_user_can( 'view_users' ) ) {`
```

But don't use `current_user_can()` for checking roles, only for checking capabilities.  It's not meant to be used for role checking, no matter how many people you see on the Interwebs telling you that it's OK.  [The WP docs tell you not to](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/).

Comment: wow!, that's more than enough for me, everything is working fine, thanks bro, didn't think anyone would help me. cheers...